# How to create a UserControl in the MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

Currently, within a real-world application development, I am struggling with the consumption of a custom `UserControl` in the MVVM pattern.

In my application, there is a `DataGrid` where the user can select an entry. The `DataGrid`'s `SelectedItem` is `TwoWay`-bound to a field of the ViewModel set as `DataContext`. When the user selects an entry, the field is properly updated (tested). In the `Page` where holds the `DataGrid`, the field is bound through XAML to a `DependencyProperty` of a custom `UserControl` devised in the MVVM pattern : it bares its own ViewModel which is set as `DataContext`. The trouble is that the `UserControl`'s `DependencyProperty` is not updated when the field changes even though the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is correctly implemented (see the comparison with a traditional control in the next minimal working example).

This example is constituted of a `Label` and bares `ViewModelUserControl` as a `DataContext`, `UserControl1`is consumed by the `MainWindow` and the binding is compared to that of a `Label`.

The file MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="UserControlWithinUserControlDataContext.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:UserControlWithinUserControlDataContext"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350" Width="525"
        >

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                >

        <ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 x:Name="listbox"
                 Height="150"
                 >
        </ListBox>

        <Local:UserControl1 Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay}"
                            Height="50" Width="150"
                            />

        <Label Content="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay}"
               />

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

The code-behind MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ViewModelWindow view_model_window
        {
            get { return _view_model; }
        }
        private ViewModelWindow _view_model = new ViewModelWindow();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = view_model_window;

            IList<String> list = new List<String>();
            list.Add("A");
            list.Add("B");
            list.Add("C");
            listbox.ItemsSource = list;
        }
    }
```

The ViewModel of the `MainWindow`, the file ViewModelWindow.cs :

```
public class ViewModelWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public String Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            if (text != value)
            {
                text = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }
    }
    private String text = "Bli";
}
```

The file UserControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlWithinUserControlDataContext.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Text}"
               Background="Magenta"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The code-behind file UserControl1.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public ViewModelUserControl view_model_usercontrol
        {
            get { return _view_model; }
        }
        private ViewModelUserControl _view_model = new ViewModelUserControl();

        public String Text
        {
            get { return (String)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(String), typeof(UserControl1),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                        new PropertyChangedCallback(TextPropertyChangedCallback)));

        private static void TextPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl1 user_control = d as UserControl1;
            if(user_control != null)
            {
                user_control.view_model_usercontrol.Text = user_control.Text;
            }
        }

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = view_model_usercontrol;
        }
    }
```

The ViewModel of `UserControl1`, the file ViewModelUserControl.cs:

```
public class ViewModelUserControl : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public String Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            if (text != value)
            {
                text = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }
    }
    private String text = "";
}
```

As you can see when executing this code, the `MainWindow`'s `Label` gets updated while the `UserControl1`'s `Label` doesn't.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to makes this works?

Many thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: Do you get any binding errors during runtime?

Comment: Even though my problem is solved, you raised a point: the fact that nothing gets updated is an error in itself, but not really debugging-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

first you do not need to add anything in the UserControl just the XAML. Remove all the code of the UserControl and try.

Let's explain why:

Content="{Binding Text}" you set this in the usercontrol xaml, it's binded to the ViewModelWindow. and that works. and remove in

```
  <Local:UserControl1 => Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Ok, but it is correct to define a property in the user control in case of other situation?, that's right, in order to do that:

```
<UserControl x:Name="UserControlInstance"...>
<Label Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=UserControlInstance}" ...>
```

Where in this case Text is the dependency property and not the datacontext property.

Try the first option, and then the second defining just a Dependency Property and in this case bind the dependency property as you did. 
And a tip, if a dependency property is in the visual element tree like in your case you do not need to call the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Juan for your answer, here is the solution for conceiving the `UserControl` in the MVVM pattern:

I gave the name `root` to the `Grid` of `UserControl1` and set its `DataContext`:

```
root.DataContext = view_model_usercontrol;
```

instead of:

```
DataContext = view_model_usercontrol;
```

Everything works fine.

Happy ending :)

Comment: This is ok when you need your UserControl to have its own ViewModel. But that's not always the case, sometimes setting no DataContext and using relative Bindings is the way to go, even for MVVM. In any case, avoid `this.DataContext = this` :P

Comment: Well, I like to keep things separate : the incoming flow of data by DependencyProperty, transmitted to the ViewModel which is set as DataContext for the outflow of data by Binding.